# number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length 3

Tags: r

```
library("xlsx")
library("lubridate")
setwd("C:/Users/Fa16Rcs028/Dropbox/Spring 17/Special Topics In HCI/Tasks/Task 6/Data Set")

for(i in 1:6) {
    Read <- paste(toString(i),".xlsx",sep="")
    Task1 <- read.xlsx(Read,1)
    time<-Task1$Time
    time<-dmy_hms(time)
    hr<-hour(time)
    zeeshan[i] <-table(hr)
 }
```

Here table(hr) is:

```
hr   3  5  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 19 21   
freq 2  1  5  9 16  5 12  8  3 15  3  1  4  8
```

Why I am having this error in my script

> In zeeshan[i] <- table(hr) :number of items to replace is not a
>   multiple of replacement length

Comment: I don't know what represents each variable. Is `zeeshan`a vector? If it is, then `table(hr)` needs to be a number or character of length 1, which I think is not the case because it is a table.

Comment: `table(hr)` will be a vector or matrix, so you can't assign it to a single element of `zeeshan` (which is presumably a vector).  You could make `zeeshan` a list and then `zeeshan[[i]]<-table(hr)` would work.

Comment: I have edit my question @AndrewGustar